# If $g_i$ generate $G$, then $x^kg_i^\pm x^{-k}$ generate $[G,G]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Suppose that under the quotient map $q: G\to [G,G]$, $g\mapsto [g]$, we have an element $x\in G$ such that $q(x)$ is a generator of $[G,G]$. Then we are asked to show that elements of the form $x^kg_i^\pm x^{-k}$ generate $[G,G]$ (here $g_i$ are generators of $G$). I am not really sure how to advance on this. I tried writing 
$$
x^k g_i x^{-k}=x^k g_i x^{-k}g_i^{-1}g_i=[x^k, g_i] g_i
$$
but I am not really sure how to proceed from here. I would appreciate a hint. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be difficult to prove because it's not true in general. Consider, for example, the smallest non-abelian group, the group $S_3$ of permutations of a $3$-element set. Its commutator subgroup is generated by either of the two $3$-cycles, so take one of those as $x$. The group $S_3$ itself is generated by any two of the three $2$-cycles, so take two of those as your $g_i$'s. Then your alleged generators $x^kg_i^\pm x^{-k}$ of $[S_3,S_3]$, being a conjugates of a $2$-cycle, are themselves $2$-cycles and are therefore not in $[S_3,S_3]$.

In general, the alleged generators $x^kg_i^\pm x^{-k}$ of $[G,G]$ will actually generate all of $G$.  So the claimed result fails unless $[G,G]=G$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This explains why I was having trouble proving it. There is a slightly stronger assumption that $G=\pi_1 X$ where $X=S^3\setminus K$ is the complement (in $S^3$ of a knot $K$). But I didn't think this really added much of a constraint to what $G$ could be

Comment: Unless I'm overlooking something, the additional information about $G$ guarantees that the claimed result is false, i.e., that $[G,G]\neq G$. The point is that the quotient of a fundamental group by its commutator subgroup (i.e., the abelianization of $\pi_1X$) is the first homology group of $X$ with $\mathbb Z$ coefficients. In the case of a knot complement $S^3\setminus K$, that homology group is $\mathbb Z$ by Alexander duality.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean for $x$ to be a generator of $G/[G,G]$?

Comment: @Hempelicious Actually I do think that is what I mean...I seem to have misunderstood the question. I will probably ask a new question.